# Select Related With Multiple Conditions

Tags: sql, django, django-models, orm

Using the Django ORM is it possible to perform a `select_related` (left join) with conditions additional to the default    `table1.id = table2.fk`

Using the example models:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    age = models.IntegerField()

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField()
```

and the raw sql

`SELECT  'Book'.*, 'Author'.'name'
FROM    'Book'
LEFT JOIN 
       'Author' 
ON     'Author'.'id' = 'Book'.'author_id'
        AND 'Author'.'age' > 18  ;<---this line here is what id like to use via the ORM`

I understand that in this simple example you can perform the filtering after the join, but that hasn't worked in my specific case. As i am doing sums across multiple left joins that require filters.

Comment: can you update with the models in question and specify your actual requirement. may be then we can find a workaround to this problem.

Answer (score -1):

```py
# gets all books which has author with age higher than 18
books = Book.objects.filter(author__age__gt=18)
```

returns queryset.

Then you can loop trough the queryset to access specific values and print them:

```py
for b in books:
    print(b.title, b.author.name, b.author.age)
```

Comment: The question specifically asks to filter based on a join, and not in a `WHERE` clause like in your example